# MediaWiki MonoBook skin showing body section only

Tags: mediawiki, skin

I am in the throes of upgrading a 1.17.0 MediaWiki instance to 1.29.3 (latest version supported by my MySQL/PHP combo). So, software is basically running, database is updated, I can navigate around. I installed the MonoBook skin (this is a new step as of 1.24.0 it seems). I only have the body section, not the toolbars at the top, left, bottom. The Special:Version page gives the info as:

MonoBook    – (cce8e7b) 20:07, 14 October 2018  GPL-2.0-or-later    The classic MediaWiki skin since 2004, named after the black-and-white photo of a book in the page background   Gabriel Wicke, Isarra Yos and others

I followed all the directions I could find, no luck. Any tips about which variables to look at, directories to check will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer yet ...

I opened a page in "view source" mode and clicked on the load.php href. The useful message was:

1.29.3/includes/resourceloader/ResourceLoader.php: MediaWiki requires the less.php parser

I have a request into my IT people to add less.php (composer require less.php/less.php) as I don't have the right privileges. I'll update after I see if that takes care of it.